# How to declare unspecified method's argument in C#

Tags: c#, class

I have this base interface, which describes the behaviours of a card player (human and AI):

```
interface ICardPlayer<T>
    where T: Carta, new()
{
    // some methods here
    T Pop(UNSPECIFIED ARGUMENTS);
}
```

Pop functions allows the CardPlayer to discard a card from his deck, but at this level I don't know if the player is an human player or an AI player.
If it's an human player, the method will be `T Pop(uint index);` but if it is an AI player the method will be `T Pop()`. In this case the method has to be without parameters because the Pop function on an AI player would call the AI's methods to discard the correct card.
So I will have also these two interfaces:

```
interface IHumanCardPlayer<T> : ICardPlayer<T>
    where T: Carta, new()
{
    // some methods here
    T Pop(uint index);
}

interface IAICardPlayer<T>
    where T: Carta, new()
{
    // some methods here
    T Pop();
}
```

I don't have to have all 2 methods: if the player is an human player, he has to call the Pop method giving it the index of the card which he would discard, and he can't call the method without arguments.
The same is if it is an AI player: he has to call the Pop method without giving it any arguments, and he can't call the method `Pop(index)`.

So, is there a way to write that `Pop(UNSPECIFIED ARGUMENTS)` in the `ICardPlayer<T>` interface or do I have to write 2 distinct Pop methods without using inheritance?

Comment: You could assign a default value to the param and check for that value. For example `T Pop(uint index = -1);`

Comment: The whole point of interfaces is to hide details of the implementation and make sure every instance has the same API. Why not define interface with `T Pop(uint index)` and simply ignore the argument in the AI.

Comment: Or make it nullable `T Pop(uint? index);`

Comment: Why is an AI player different from a human player?  They should both be able to take the same sort of actions, so the player interface should model the actions a player--any player--can take.  The interface shouldn't care whether it's a human sitting in front of a keyboard, a machine playing on a computer, or a lizard person feeding punch-cards into a machine.

Answer (score 3):

That would defeat the purpose of an interface, since it would be impossible to call the method (any possible call may have the wrong arguments for the particular subclass).

You can't do that.

Comment: I feel like "can't" is incorrect and misleading. You certainly can accomplish what the OP wants to do. It may not fit into the 'correct' paradigm. But at that point its rather opinionated.

Answer (score 3):

First, you're not using inheritance. That isn't necessarily good or bad.

Second, you can't, and it's a good thing.

Interfaces represent some kind of public interface that exposes access to a common set of functionality. In general, any implementation of the interface should be equally valid - they should be interchangeable, and the code that uses those interfaces shouldn't care about which specific implemetation you're being given. Obviously, this is not true in your case - you want to invoke the interface with different arguments based on what *specific* implementation you're taking. That goes against the whole idea of using interfaces (and inheritance) in the first place.

However, you just painted yourself in the corner needlessly. You made the interface too big, so to speak, as evidenced by your need to have two separate sets of arguments to the same method.

Instead, separate the human behaviour and AI behaviour on a different level. `ICardPlayer` will *always* take the `int` argument. The only difference is how the argument is produced in a different place - in case of a human player, it is the product of the UI that asks him for a card to pick. In the case of an AI player, it's produced by some algorithm.

So you'll have an interface that represents the action "picking a card":

```
interface IPlayer
{
  int PickCardToDiscard();
}
```

And you leave the how to the implementation:

```
public class HumanPlayer: IPlayer
{
  private readonly IGui gui;

  public HumanPlayer(IGui gui)
  {
    this.gui = gui;
  }

  public int PickCardToDiscard()
  {
    return gui.AskForCardSelection("Pick a card to discard.");
  }
}

public class StupidPlayer: IPlayer
{
  public int PickCardToDiscard()
  {
    return 42; // Feeling lucky
  }
}
```

Now your interfaces are consistent, and you've moved the specific implementations to the place they belong. When *instantiating* the `ICardPlayer`, you always *know* whether you want a human player or an AI player. But that's the *only* place where you care. There's the power of the abstraction - well designed interfaces allow you to isolate yourself from the specifics and focus on the abstract (which is a much smaller problem space). When the game engine wants to pick a card, all it has to do is call

```
var cardToDiscard = deck.Pop(player.PickCardToDiscard());
```

It doesn't care whether the player is a human or an AI, and it gives you opportunities to wire in other implementations as well - like different AI strategies, or a human playing over the network.

Remember, every piece of code better pay for itself - if it's not beneficial, it's actively detriminal. The same goes for abstractions in general - if the abstraction doesn't pay rent, fix it or lose it. In your case, the abstraction is clearly silly - it doesn't work even for the very first two cases you explicitly designed it for. It's the kind of thing you might do if you have an assignment like "Write code using interfaces", and you have no idea how to design interfaces that actually add value to your code. There's no point in interfaces for interface sake, or in abstractions for abstraction sake. Mkae code pay rent.

Finally, there's cases where having optional parameters makes sense. But the key point is that those parameters *must* still be part of the contract, and all implementations *must* be equally valid. For example, you might have a logging interface like this:

```
interface ILogger
{
  void Log(string message, int? severity);
}
```

You can specify severity, or you can use `null` - but the choice doesn't depend on the specific implementation of `ILogger`, it only depends on the caller - sometimes, he wants to specify a severity, and sometimes he doesn't.

Comment: thank you very much, I've understood much more about interfaces :)